# Windsor Typed Factory with Open Generic Interface

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, factory-pattern

In my application, I want to take dependencies on multiple repositories in a class, where not all of them are required each time.  Rather than constructing an instance of each one where unnecessary, I use the [Typed Factory facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/%28S%28kwaa14uzdj55gv55dzgf0vui%29%29/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) in Windsor.

However, registering a factory for each repository is a bit tiresome, and I would like to replace this with an open generic registration.  What I want to do is something like the following:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IFactory<IRepository<>>>().AsFactory()
);
```

However, this is a syntax error because of the missing type parameter for IRepository.  Is there a syntax I can use which would make this work?

NB: I'm aware that I can register an untyped Factory interface and use this to create multiple components.  I'm not interested in doing this as this is essentially taking a dependency on a service locator - if I've not registered a dependency then I won't know about it until the code tries to use it - with my approach I know about this in the constructor even though I'm not creating an instance yet.

Full (simplified) sample below:

```
public class TestA { }
public class TestB { }
public interface IRepository<T> { T Create();    }
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public T Create() { return Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); }
}

public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create();
    void Release(T instance);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(
            // Individual registrations of repositories here are fine
            Component.For<IRepository<TestA>>().ImplementedBy<Repository<TestA>>(),
            Component.For<IRepository<TestB>>().ImplementedBy<Repository<TestB>>()
        );

        container.Register(
            // Individual registrations of factories - works, but trying to avoid!
            Component.For<IFactory<IRepository<TestA>>>().AsFactory(),
            Component.For<IFactory<IRepository<TestB>>>().AsFactory()
        );

        container.Register(
            // Generic Registration of Factories - syntax errors
            // Component.For<IFactory<IRepository<>>>().AsFactory()
            // Component.For(typeof(IFactory<IRepository<>>)).AsFactory()
        );

        var factoryA = container.Resolve<IFactory<IRepository<TestA>>>();
        var factoryB = container.Resolve<IFactory<IRepository<TestB>>>();

        var repoA = factoryA.Create();
        var repoB = factoryB.Create();

        Console.WriteLine("Everything worked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your factory inteface definition is a little too "open". Change your factory interface as follows:

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory<T>
{
    IRepository<T> Create();
    void Release(IRepository<T> instance);
}
```

And you can then register:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepositoryFactory<>)).AsFactory());
```

And resolve:

```
var factoryA = container.Resolve<IRepositoryFactory<TestA>>();
var factoryB = container.Resolve<IRepositoryFactory<TestB>>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "too open" part of the interface was what gave the ability to verify dependencies before use.  Your solution still allows me to take a dependency on IRepositoryFactory<Foo> when there is no IRepository<Foo> registered.  Your answer has made me think this won't be possible to do in a single step like I hoped though.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Isn't it the case that using a container with dependencies specified in terms of interfaces will always allow you to take a dependency on something that's not registered? Isn't that the idea of the container to keep things decoupled?

Comment: No - the code in my question where I've individually registered the interface factories prevents me taking a dependency on `IFactory<IRepository<Foo>>` if `IRepository<Foo>` isn't registered without actually needing to instantiate it. I was hoping to find an easier way of doing this without individual registrations.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say it "prevents me taking a dependency". Can you explain further? It seems to me you can take a dependency on anything that the compiler regards as semantically valid. Whether it actually is available at runtime or not can only be known at runtime. It seems to me the only thing that will "prevent" it is the runtime exception that occurs when the resolve is attempted. As @Steven has pointed out, verifying the correctness of your container configuration is best done by other means such as unit or integration tests.

Comment: Probably bad choice of words.  What I meant was, my earlier code gives an exception at the constructor for a missing dependency, your approach waits until you try to use the item from the factory.  I'm aware you'll never catch these issues at compile time.

Comment: I get where you're coming from now but it's not correct. If you fail to register a component for IRepository<TestB>, both my code and your code will fail at the same point: `var repoB = factoryB.Create()`. Both your code and my code will happily return a factory. It will only be when you attempt to use the factory that you will discover the error.

Comment: I think my answer provides what you were asking for: it shows the shorthand way of factory registration while maintaining long-hand repository registration and with no difference in output.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pattern for grouping repositories together. It is called [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). So, instead of creating a factory for creating repositories, create a unit of work class that references these repositories. For instance:

```cs
public abstract class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    // here is your factory
    protected abstract IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>();

    public IRepository<User> Users
    {
        get { return this.GetRepository<User>();
    }

    public IRepository<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return this.GetRepository<Customer>();
    }

    // etc..
}
```

In your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) you can define an `UnitOfWork` implementation that holds a reference to Windsor and enables you to get `IRepository<T>` implementations:

```cs
internal sealed class WindsorUnitOfWork : UnitOfWork
{
    private WindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorUnitOfWork(WindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    protected override IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()
    {
        return this.container.Resolve<IRepository<T>>();
    }
}
```

And register it as follows:

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<UnitOfWork>()
    .ImplementedBy<WindsorUnitOfWork>()
        .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Consumers now have a really convenient way of using the repositories:

```cs
private readonly UnitOfWork db;

public KarmaService(UnitOfWork db)
{
    this.db = db;
}

public int CalculateKarmaForActiveUsersByName(string name)
{
    var users =
        from user in this.db.Users
        where user.Name == name
        where user.Active
        select user;

    return users.Sum(user => user.Karma);
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of UoW, however it's not what I was asking for.  I'm specifically trying to see if I can use the registration pattern on Typed Factories I'm asking for here.  Pretend my classes aren't IRepository<T> if it helps - they were picked as something people would relate to.  Additionally, your `WindsorUoW` class is still essentially a service locator, and unregistered repositories won't be detected until something tries to use them.

Comment: @Richard: I can't answer your question without the context of the `IReposity<T>`. My knowledge of Windsor doesn't go that deep. Note that the `WindsorUoW` is absolutely NOT a service locator, since it is defined in your composition root (or at least - it should be). In that case it's simply part of your infrastructure. It is an infrastructure component. Take a look at [this excellent post from Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx) about this subject.

Comment: The point is that in your code, when you call `CalculateKarmaForActiveUsersByName`, *that* is the point at which you'll get an exception because you've not taken a dependency on IRepository<Users> (assuming it wasn't registered, which is exactly what I'm trying to address) - you've got a class which can locate and create it.  This is, in my view (and my reading of your linked articles) still being a Service Locator.  If your UnitOfWork class took dependencies on the Repos instead of the container, things would be different.

Comment: Since the `GetRepository<T>` method returns a specific type of objects (repositories) instead of any type of object, we can't speak of a Service Locator, although it has the same bad characteristic of the Service Locator, in that you loose the possibility to let the container verify the object graph for you. If you want to fix this in the application design, you will have to inject ALL repositories through the constructor, which is not a good alternative...

Comment: It's very good practice to keep your container configuration verifiable (or to verify the configuration). Instead, you should try a different approach to verify the correctness of your configuration. For instance, you can solve this with an integration test (or test that runs at application start up), where you test the creation of all repositories defined on the `UnitOfWork` (using reflection like this: `typeof(UnitOfWork).GetProperty().Select(p => p.PropertyType).ToList().ForEach(t => container.Resolve(t))`.